# Giving labels names with array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, label

Okay, so i'm trying to give 7 different labels names using an array and a for loop.

Code:

```
id huller[] = {hul18.text, hul17.text, hul16.text, hul15.text, hul14.text, hul13.text, hul12.text, hul11.text, hul10.text, hul9.text, hul8.text, hul7.text, hul6.text, hul5.text, hul4.text, hul3.text, hul2.text, hul1.text};

for (int i = 0;  7 > i; i++) {
    huller[i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x + 1];
    NSLog(@"%@", huller[i]);
}
```

The name change in the NSLog, but they do not change in the simulator. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming hul18, hul17, etc. are all UILabel objects, then do this:

```
NSArray *labels = [ hul18, hul17, hul16, hul15, hul14, hul13, hul12, hul11, hul10, hul9, hul8, hul7, hul6, hul5, hul4, hul3, hul2, hul1 ];

// Change the text of every label in the array
for (int i = 0;  i < labels.count; i++) {
    UILabel *label = labels[i];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x + 1]; // Do you really want 'x' here or 'i'?
    NSLog(@"%@", label.text);
}
```

Comment: this method gives me this warning: -[__NSCFString setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a1d4b0
(But yes i do want x and not i :))

Comment: This implies the 'labels' array has NSString objects and not UILabel objects. Does your 'labels' array match the code I posted? Is hul18 and the others UILabel objects?

Comment: I changed it, and now I got this error -[UILabel objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74b9e70
:(

Comment: You must be trying use the subscript notation on a UILabel object instead of an NSArray object. Without seeing your code it is impossible to help.

Comment: Oh found the error, and your method worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to change too, then you have to set the text manually.

```
NSArray *labels = //Array of labels;
for (int i = 0;  7 > i; i++) {
    huller[i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x + 1];
    labels[i].text = huller[i];
    NSLog(@"%@", huller[i]);
}
```